# how to parse variables using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Assume there is a string "aaaa/{helloworld}/dddd/{good}/ccc", 
I want to get an array which contains the variables "helloworld" and "good" which are in braces {}.
Is there a simple way to implement this using regex?
Below function doesn't work:

```js
function parseVar(str) {
 var re = /\{.*\}/; // new RegExp('{[.*]}');// /{.*}/;
 var m = str.match(re);
 console.log(m)
 if (m != null) {
  console.log((m));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
 }
}

parseVar("aaaa/{helloworld}/dddd/{good}/ccc");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global flag (g) allow the regex to find more than one match. `.*` is greedy, meaning it will take up as many characters as possible but you don't want that so you have to use `?` which makes it take up as little characters as possible. It is helpful to use [regex101](https://regex101.com) to test regular expressions.

```js
function parseVar(str) {
  var re = /\{(.*?)\}/g;
  var results = []
  var match = re.exec(str);
  while (match != null) {
    // matched text: match[0]
    // match start: match.index
    // capturing group n: match[n]
    results.push(match[1])
    match = re.exec(str);
  }
  return results
}

var r = parseVar("aaaa/{helloworld}/dddd/{good}/ccc")
document.write(JSON.stringify(r))
```

Comment: The OP seems to want the results **without** the curly brackets.